# IIS7 Failed Request Tracing Permissions

Tags: iis-7, trace, event-viewer

In the event viewer, around every 5 minutes I am getting the event described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735145(WS.10).aspx

> "FailedRequestTracing module failed to create directory '%3'. No logs
>   will be generated until this condition is corrected. The problem
>   happened at least %1 times in the last %2 minutes. The data is the
>   error."

The fix is supposed to be allowing IIS_IUSRS write access to that directory.

Not only did IIS_IUSRS have write access, but I have also allowed IUSR, NETWORK SERVICE and the plesk panel IUSR accounts for all 3 of my domains, and I am still getting the error.

I can't help but think this is something really stupid with Plesk Panel. Fairly sure that every weird problem I've had has stemmed from Plesk, unfortunately my server was pre-configured with it. Is there a way to find out what user IIS is trying to access the log files with so I simply grant it permission?

Comment: After being perplexed by this for some time, I eventually decided that I could just ignore this error, as I do not examine `FailedRequestTracing` logs (ever)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not that you don't have correct permissions, it's about having multiple application pools and hence, instances of the native FailedRequestsTracingModule running.

> The failed request tracing directory is created per-site and not
>   per-app-pool - so if you have multiple apps running under multiple
>   app-pools, they will each try to use the next filename in sequence and
>   hence fail - we could probably add some retry logic to try other
>   numbers in case of such collision.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1158660.aspx?Failed+Request+Tracing+Event+2284

Comment: Can you provide a few options as possible solutions?

Comment: @WarlikeChimpanzee - one solution is to fix the issues that are causing you to turn on FailedRequestsTracingModule, and then turn it off. It's not meant to be left on all the time.